# Footnotetext hanging, no superscript, numbers left aligned

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

What I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{2em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\quad}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{Lorem Ipsum}\footnote[10]{Sequi quas cupiditate dolor voluptatibus ratione ipsam. Sit non dolor est esse harum error. Incidunt tempora voluptates harum velit eveniet consequatur. Aut id sunt repellat repellat omnis quibusdam provident totam.}\footnote[100]{Cumque porro sit est possimus beatae consequatur.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the number to be aligned to the left and not to the right. Something like this:

[image]

But I do not know how to do this with `scrextend`. With `footmisc` I could not find how to get non superscripted text for the number.

I know that there are quite a few questions about footnotes, their indentation and about non superscripted numbers in footnotes but I could not find a combination of them and couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply wrap it in a parbox. In this example you can adjust the `100` according to your maximum of needed footnotes (changes width). Probably you should turn it into `1000` to have a better separation of number and content.

[image: footnotes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\newlength\fnnumber
\newbox\fnbox
\setbox\fnbox=\hbox{100}
\setlength{\fnnumber}{\wd\fnbox}
\deffootnote{\fnnumber}{0em}{\parbox[t]{\fnnumber}{\raggedright\thefootnotemark}}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{Lorem Ipsum}\footnote[10]{Sequi quas cupiditate dolor voluptatibus ratione ipsam. Sit non dolor est esse harum error. Incidunt tempora voluptates harum velit eveniet consequatur. Aut id sunt repellat repellat omnis quibusdam provident totam.}\footnote[100]{Cumque porro sit est possimus beatae consequatur.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this code the number is placed a bit deeper than the text. Do you know why?

Comment: @Georg Does `\deffootnote{2em}{0em}{\parbox[t]{\fnnumber}{\raggedright\thefootnotemark}}` help (see the `[t]`)?

Comment: Thanks now it works. One suggestion. Instead of `2em` we should now use `\fnnumber`.

Comment: @Georg You're right, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Set the maximum width of the footnote number at begin document and use a box with the specified alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\newlength\footnotenumberwidth
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\footnotenumberwidth}{\footnotesize 100 }%
}

\deffootnote[\footnotenumberwidth]{\footnotenumberwidth}{0pt}{%
  \makebox[\footnotenumberwidth][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}

\begin{document}

\footnote{Lorem Ipsum}%
\footnote[10]{Sequi quas cupiditate dolor voluptatibus ratione ipsam.
  Sit non dolor est esse harum error. Incidunt tempora voluptates
  harum velit eveniet consequatur. Aut id sunt repellat repellat
  omnis quibusdam provident totam.}%
\footnote[200]{Cumque porro sit est possimus beatae consequatur.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that also works perfectly. (The `\makebox` should get the Argument `[l]` instead of `[r]`)

Comment: @Georg Fixed; apparently I cannot stand that kind of alignment. `;-)`